# Nodejs Date object to protobuf

Tags: node.js, protobuf.js

I am building a graphql integrated with protobuf. I have an gql schema like:

```
type User {
  userId: ID!,
  createTime: DateTime 
}
```

The problem is how can i create an `User` message object by only the constructor? Be specify, I would want to do:
`message = new User(['my_user_id', '2018-10-01']).toObject()` so that it will convert to a correct protobuf message object to me. like:

```
{    
  "userId": "my_user_id",
  "createTime": {
    "seconds": 15000000,
    "nanos": 0
  }
}
```

However, the createTime is always `undefined`

I have tried a lot of way, still not working (there are very less online resouces are talking about nodejs protobuf timestamp by the way)

I tried `message = new User(['my_user_id', '2018-10-01T20:23:32.000Z']).toObject()` not working

I tried `message = new User(['my_user_id', new Date()]).toObject()`, not working

I tried

```
let timestamp = new proto.google.protobuf.Timestamp()
timestamp.setSeconds(1)
timestamp.setNanos(1)
message = new User(['my_user_id',timestamp]).toObject()
```

not working either

Does anyone know to correct way to do this? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Just do `new User(['my_user_id', [1538425412, 0]]).toObject()` and will give the correct message object

```
{
  "userId": "my_user_id",
  "createTime": {
    "seconds": 1538425412,
    "nanos": 0
  }
}
```